# How to Convert Regular Expression Patterns From Javascript to Python?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, python-3.x

The following Javascript code (which i did not write) uses regular expressions in order to extract v2/v3 onion addresses from code.

From the following website:

https://github.com/k4m4/onion-regex

```
'use strict';
const v2 = '[a-z2-7]{16}\.onion';
const v3 = '[a-z2-7]{56}\.onion';


const onion = opts => opts && opts.exact ?
    new RegExp(`(?:^${v2}$)|(?:^${v3}$)`) :
    new RegExp(`${v2}|${v3}`, 'g');

 onion.v2 = opts => opts && opts.exact ? new RegExp(`^${v2}$`) : new 
 RegExp(`${b}${v2}${b}`, 'g');
 onion.v3 = opts => opts && opts.exact ? new RegExp(`^${v3}$`) : new 
 RegExp(`${b}${v3}${b}`, 'g');

module.exports = onion;
```

I am looking to convert these regular expressions into ones usable by python in order to augment existing analysis code.

So how would i convert so the regex in the first block of code to regular expressions that replace the regex below:

```
import re
import requests




r = requests.get('https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/NextGenOnions#Howtoconnecttothetesthubfornextgenonionservices')  
print(r.text)
stringforanalysis = str(r.text)
#^(?:[a-z2-7]{16}|[a-z2-7]{56})\.onion$

v3s = re.findall(r"^(?:[a-z2-7]{16}|[a-z2-7]{56})\.onion$", stringforanalysis)
v2s = re.findall(r"^(?:[a-z2-7]{16}|[a-z2-7]{56})\.onion", stringforanalysis)
print("v2 and 3")
print(v3s)
print(v2s)
```

The eventual output should be a list of version 2 and version 3

Comment: Can't figure out what onion.v2 or v3 should be because don't know what `${b}` is.

Comment: The first 2 substitution's resolve to `^(?:[a-z2-7]{16}|[a-z2-7]{56})\.onion$` and `(?:[a-z2-7]{16}|[a-z2-7]{56})\.onion` basically the same thing, one uses anchors `^$`

Comment: To fit them into your url, I imagine would be this `^https?://(?:[\w.-]{16}|[\w.-]{56})\.onion$` and `https?://(?:[\w.-]{16}|[\w.-]{56})\.onion`

Comment: And your second one `^(?:https?://)?(?:[\w.-]{16}|[\w.-]{56})\.onion$` and `(?:https?://)?(?:[\w.-]{16}|[\w.-]{56})\.onion`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, i'll refine the question

Comment: it seems one of them worked actually